# How to reconnect to a Server automatilly when server availble in java sockets

Tags: java, multithreading, sockets

I have java client server application. Server is running or may not be connected. but we need to connect with ip and port.

```
Socket s=new Socket(ip,port);
```

if it is connected, socket will be created, else it throws `IOException`. then i will set a status of that connection as not connected in an object. 
if connected, i will send data as commands. It will respond to that command with data. We send commands with output stream and read responce with input-stream of the socket.

I need to automatically reconnect to the server when server is available (wired or wifi connection).

How to Use Multi threading here

ex:

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.InetSocketAddress;
import java.net.Socket;
public class ConnectionThread implements Runnable {
    static class ConnectionStatus {
        boolean connected = false;

        public boolean isConnected() {
            return connected;
        }
        public void setConnected(boolean connected) {
            this.connected = connected;
        }
    }
    ConnectionStatus status;
    Socket socket;
    String ip;
    int port;
    public ConnectionThread(ConnectionStatus status, String ip, int port) {
        this.status = status;
        this.ip = ip;
        this.port = port;
    }
    public void connectAgain() throws IOException {
        while (!status.isConnected()) {
            socket = new Socket(ip, port);
            status.setConnected(true);
        }
    }
    public void run() {
        try {
            connectAgain();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            try {
                Thread.sleep(1000);
                connectAgain();
            } catch (InterruptedException e1) {
                e1.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e1) {
                e1.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ConnectionStatus status = new ConnectionStatus();
        status.setConnected(false);
        ConnectionThread cthread = new ConnectionThread(status, "192.166.102.201", 1986);
        Thread x = new Thread(cthread);
        x.start();
        System.out.println("Connected ..." + status.isConnected());
    }
}
```

I need to send commands (data) only when connected to receive response.

I need to set the connected status to false when not connected
and to true when connected.

Based on connected status i will read from socket or write to socket steams.

I need to know when the connection is failed
and when the connection is available.

I think better to use propertychangelistener when connected property is changed.

is it right?

Answer (score 0):

This loop really has no point.

```
while (!status.isConnected()) {
        socket = new Socket(ip, port);
        status.setConnected(true);
}
```

Whether it succeeds or fails it can never execute the loop more than once. It has exactly the same effect as just this:

```
socket = new Socket(ip, port);
status.setConnected(true);
```

The run will call this twice with a 1 second delay unless it doesn't throw an exception and succeeds. If you want it to keep trying until you connect, you need to catch the exception within the loop. eg

```
Socket s = new Socket();
SocketAddress sa = new InetSocketAddress("192.166.102.201", 1986);
while (!s.isConnected()) {
    try {
        s.connect(sa); // try the connection
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        // ignore we may have to try lots of times
        try {
            Thread.sleep(1000);
        } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
           // not sure how to handle this, maybe we should just give up. 
        }
    }
}
```

**Update:** I had both the sleep and the connect in the same try block which meant it would never sleep but just keep the thread always busy. Moved the sleep to separate block.